# como invocar los metodos set y get desde el main

Tags: java, get, set

me dejaron de tarea un codigo que permita hacer depositos y retiros de una cuenta bancaria, ya tengo todo hecho el problema es que el profesor dijo que debo hacer los procesos desde un metodo y no entiendo como invocar los metodos set y get a la clase principal, el codigo que subo ahi tiene la version mal hecha donde los procesos los hice con un switch, soy nuevo aqui, espero me puedan compartir un tutorial o algun libro que me ayude a resolver esto, y mucho mejor si son consejos, gracias
[Enlace](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14d6J4LWlAjgRs_kaU7X5MsKjEo19zWJg)

```java
package cooperativa.adriancito;


public class datosa {
      private int numero_de_cuenta;
   private String Nombre;
   private String Apellido;
   private String Direccion;
   private float  saldo;
   private float retiros;
   private float deposito;

    public datosa(int numero_de_cuenta, String Nombre, String Apellido, String Direccion, float saldo, float retiros, float deposito) {
        this.numero_de_cuenta = numero_de_cuenta;
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.Apellido = Apellido;
        this.Direccion = Direccion;
        this.saldo = saldo;
       this.retiros = retiros;
        this.deposito = deposito;
    }

    public int getNumero_de_cuenta() {
        return numero_de_cuenta;
    }

    public void setNumero_de_cuenta(int nca) {
        this.numero_de_cuenta = nca;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nom) {
        this.Nombre = nom;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return Apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String Apel) {
        this.Apellido = Apel;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return Direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String Dire) {
        this.Direccion = Dire;
    }

    public float getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(float sal) {
        this.saldo = sal;
    } 

    public float getRetiros() {
        return retiros;
    }

    public void setRetiros(float reti) {
        this.saldo = saldo - retiros; 
    }

    public float getDeposito() {
        return deposito;
    }

    public void setDeposito(float depo) {
        this.saldo = saldo + deposito; 
    }

}
package cooperativa.adriancito;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class CooperativaAdriancito {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String nom, Dire, Apel;
       int nca, opci;
       float sal, reti, depo;

       datosa datos[] = new datosa[2];
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

       for(int i=0; i<datos.length; i++){
       System.out.println("ingrese su nombre " + (i+1) + " : ");
       nom = sc.next();
       System.out.println("ingrese su apellido " + (i+1) + " : ");
       Apel = sc.next();
       System.out.println("ingrese su direccion " + (i+1) + " : ");
       Dire = sc.next();  
       System.out.println("ingrese su numero de cuenta " + (i+1) + " : ");
       nca = sc.nextInt();
       System.out.println("ingrese su saldo " + (i+1) + " : ");
       sal = sc.nextFloat();

       System.out.println("si desea hacer un retiro digite 1 si desea hacer un deposito digite 2");
        opci=sc.nextInt();
        switch(opci){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("ingrese cuanto desea retirar");
                reti=sc.nextFloat();
                sal = sal - reti;
            break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("ingrese cuanto desea depositar");
                depo=sc.nextFloat();
                sal = sal + depo;
            break;
        }
                System.out.println("su saldo es" + sal);   
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Hola!, para que podarmos ayudarte, por favor añade el código en formato de texto aquí en tu pregunta! :)

Comment: Hola para insertar código basta con seleccionarlo y presionar ctrl + k o seleccionarlo y presionar el icono de `{}` lo de las comillas invertidas y el lenguaje no es nada recomendado

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer es que en lugar de guardarlos en variables propias dentro del main, quieres usar los atributos de  datosa para guardarlos??

Answer (score 1):

Asi haces una llamada a la clase y con el nombre de variable introducido ya puedes llamar cada metodo.

```
datosa datos = new datosa();
datos.getSalario();
```

Comment: cuando lo hago me dice cannot find simbol, no entiendo por qué

Answer (score -1):

Primero tienes que crear los metodos setters y getters, en eclipse por ejemplo puedes hacerlo desde el mismo programa, pulsando en source y luego importar getters y setters, luego en la clase principal puedes invocarlos como bien dijo el compañero usando el .getNombreDelMetodo();

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda, un saludo.

Edit:

[Enlace](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h5IPdktiionlqOMlIHir6iuUgxkxr5lc)

He estado mirando tu proyecto java desde el enlace y he modificado tu código para que puedas invocar los métodos setters y getters desde la clase principal. Échale un vistazo para que puedas ver lo que te faltaba y eso, espero que te sirva.

```java
------
package cooperativa.adriancito;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CooperativaAdriancito {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String nca = "", nom="",Apel="",Dire="";
        int opci=0;
        float sal=0,reti=0,depo=0;
        char euro = '€';

       datosa datos = new datosa(nca, nom, Apel, Dire, sal, reti, depo);

       System.out.println("ingrese su nombre: ");
       datos.setNombre(nom);
       System.out.println("ingrese su apellido: ");
       datos.setApellido(Apel);
       System.out.println("ingrese su direccion: ");
       datos.setDireccion(Dire);
       System.out.println("ingrese su numero de cuenta: ");
       datos.setNumero_de_cuenta(nca);
       System.out.println("ingrese su saldo: ");
       datos.setSaldo(sal);

       System.out.println("\nNombre: "+datos.getNombre()+" \nApellido: "+datos.getApellido()+" \nDireccion: "+datos.getDireccion()+" \nNúmero de cuenta: "+datos.getNumero_de_cuenta()+" \nSaldo: "+datos.getSaldo()+euro);

       System.out.println("\nSi desea hacer un retiro digite 1. \nSi desea hacer un deposito digite 2");
       opci=sc.nextInt();
       switch(opci){
           case 1:
               System.out.println("Ingrese cuanto desea retirar.");
               datos.setRetiros(reti);
               sal = datos.getSaldo() - datos.getRetiros();
           break;
           case 2:
               System.out.println("Ingrese cuanto desea depositar.");
               datos.setDeposito(depo);
               sal = datos.getSaldo() + datos.getDeposito();
           break;
       }
               System.out.println("Su saldo es de " + sal+euro);
               sc.close();

    }
}
-------
package cooperativa.adriancito;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class datosa {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   private String numero_de_cuenta;
   private String Nombre;
   private String Apellido;
   private String Direccion;
   private float  saldo;
   private float retiros;
   private float deposito;

    public float getRetiros() {
    return retiros;
}
public void setRetiros(float retiros) {
    this.retiros = sc.nextFloat();
}
public float getDeposito() {
    return deposito;
}
public void setDeposito(float deposito) {
    this.deposito = sc.nextFloat();
}
    public datosa(String numero_de_cuenta, String Nombre, String Apellido, String Direccion, float saldo, float retiros, float deposito) {
        this.numero_de_cuenta = numero_de_cuenta;
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.Apellido = Apellido;
        this.Direccion = Direccion;
        this.saldo = saldo;
        this.retiros = retiros;
        this.deposito = deposito;
    }
public String getNumero_de_cuenta() {
    return numero_de_cuenta;
}
public void setNumero_de_cuenta(String numero_de_cuenta) {
    this.numero_de_cuenta = sc.nextLine();
}
public String getNombre() {
    return Nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    Nombre = sc.nextLine();
}
public String getApellido() {
    return Apellido;
}
public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    Apellido = sc.nextLine();
}
public String getDireccion() {
    return Direccion;
}
public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    Direccion = sc.nextLine();
}
public float getSaldo() {
    return saldo;
}
public void setSaldo(float saldo) {
    this.saldo = sc.nextFloat();
}


}
```

Solo necesitas esas dos clases, prueba a ejecutarlo y verás como todo funciona. Un saludo.

Comment: es que ya hago todo eso pero al momento de invocarlos me marca como si estuviera mal y de verdad no entiendo donde está el error

Comment: Entonces mejor muéstranos tu código aquí para poder entenderlo mejor.

Comment: lo puse en el enlace es que no me deja publicar el codigo me dice que no tiene el formato del codigo jaja y deverdad que estoy muy estresado con todo esto que preferi subirlo así que arreglarlo, si puedes revisarlo descargandolo te lo agradecería

Comment: Para poner tu código debes poner tres comillas inversas y el nombre del lenguaje y al final del código pones de nuevo 3 comillas inversas.

Comment: ya lo hice ahi esta la clase secundaria

Comment: pero si intento agregar la principal me marca error denuevo jaja

Comment: Puedes ponerlo dentro del mismo, es decir, separarlo tu mismo ya sea poniendo guiones como una linea o un asteriscos cada vez que comience una clase, todo dentro del mismo enlace que has puesto.

Comment: ahora si ya lo hice

Comment: Ya le eché un vistazo a tu código y lo he corregido, échale un vistazo y ejecútalo para que veas como funciona, un saludo.

Comment: te agradezco un montón, me puedes recomendar un canal para ver tutoriales sobre esto? enserio mil gracias estaba apunto de morir del coraje de no saber que hacer jaja, solo me queda seguir estudiando y analizar el codigo

Comment: De nada para eso estamos, yo también estoy empezando y si quieres puedo recomendarte los cursos que he hecho y vídeos que he visto. Busca en google codigofacilito, ahí hice 2 cursos de java, y en youtube busca pildorasinformaticas, ahí también he aprendido bastante, espero que te ayude tanto como a mi, un saludo.